# Slick Slider Width issue with WP 5.6 editor & ACF Pro

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slick.js

This is a bit of a specific issue, but I'm hoping I'm not alone with it!

After updating to WP 5.6, all of my websites are having issues rendering a Slick Slider in the Block Editor. On the front-end, the sliders are fine.

I believe the issue is that if I have a block with Slick Slider inside it, and that block is set to 'full width' in the WP editor, Slick Slider is unable to find the correct size of the window within the block editor. The sliders then expand beyond the viewport, pushing the block editor settings box off-screen and making the editor pretty unusable.

As the title suggests, I'm using the latest version of slick slider, and I'm rendering this through a custom ACF Block within WP 5.6.

Prior to 5.6 everything rendered just fine. I'm hoping the solution is a simple CSS change, but I can't for the life of my find something that works.

Here is my code:

### ACF block

```
acf_register_block_type(array(
        'name'              => 'image-slider',
        'title'             => __('Image Slider'),
        'description'       => __('A slider of images.'),
        'render_template'   => get_template_directory().'/inc/blocks/core/image-slider.php',
        'render_callback'   => 'render_block__image_slider',
        'category'          => 's2f-blocks',
        'icon'              => 'images-alt2',
        'keywords'          => array( 'slider', 'images', 's2f' ),
        //'mode'                => false
    ));
    if( !function_exists('render_block__image_slider') ) {
        function render_block__image_slider( $block, $content = '', $is_preview = false, $post_id = 0 ) {
            include(get_template_directory().'/inc/blocks/core/image-slider.php');
        }
    }
```

### ACF block render template

```
/**
 * @param   array $block The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content The block inner HTML (empty).
 * @param   bool $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 * @param   (int|string) $post_id The post ID this block is saved to.
 */

$block_name = 'image-slider-block';

// Create id attribute allowing for custom "anchor" value.
$id = 'slider-' . $block['id'];
if( !empty($block['anchor']) ) {
    $id = $block['anchor'];
}

// Create class attribute allowing for custom "className" and "align" values.
$className = $block_name;
if( !empty($block['className']) ) {
    $className .= ' ' . $block['className'];
}
if( !empty($block['align']) ) {
    $className .= ' align' . $block['align'];
}
if( $is_preview ) {
    $className .= ' is-admin';
}

$slidesToShow = get_field('slides_to_show') ?: '3';

$lightbox = get_field('lightbox_images') ?: false;
if( $lightbox ) {
    $className .= ' is-lightbox';
}

$crop = get_field('crop_images') ?: false;
if( $crop ) {
    $className .= ' is-cropped';
}

$arrows = get_field('show_arrows') ?: false;
if( $arrows ) {
    $className .= ' has-arrows';
}

$slides = get_field('slides');


?>
<div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="slider <?php echo esc_attr($className); ?> wp-block">
    <?php if( $slides ): ?>
        <div class="slides" data-slides="<?php echo $slidesToShow; ?>">
            <?php foreach($slides as $slide) : ?>
                <div class="slide text-center">
                    <?php if( $lightbox ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($slide['image']['id'], 'large', false); ?>" data-fancybox="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                            
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $slide['image']['id'], 'large' ); ?>
                            
                    <?php if( $lightbox ) : ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p>Please add some slides.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

### Slick Slider JS

```
/**
         * initializeBlock
         *
         * Adds custom JavaScript to the block HTML.
         *
         * @date    15/4/19
         * @since   1.0.0
         *
         * @param   object $block The block jQuery element.
         * @param   object attributes The block attributes (only available when editing).
         * @return  void
         */
        var initialiseSliderImageBlock = function( $block ) {
            
            var slider = $block.find('.slides');
            var slidesToShow = slider.data('slides');
            var arrows = false;

            if( !slidesToShow ) {
                slidesToShow = 3;
            }

            if( isAdmin() ) {
                var container = $block.find('.image-slider-block');
                if( container.hasClass('has-arrows') ) {
                    arrows = true;
                }
            } else {
                if( $block.hasClass('has-arrows')) {
                    arrows = true;
                }
            }

            
            
            // init slider
            slider.find('.slide').each(function() {
                $(this).addClass('show-slide');
            });
            
            if( !slider.hasClass('slick-slider') ) {
                slider.slick({
                    dots: true,
                    arrows: arrows,
                    infinite: false,
                    speed: 300,
                    slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
                    autoplay: false,
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1300,
                            settings: {
                                dots: true,
                                arrows: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1100,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: Math.ceil(slidesToShow/2),
                                dots: true,
                                arrows: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 700,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                                dots: true,
                                arrows: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 450,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                dots: true,
                                arrows: false
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                });
                
                slider.on('init beforeChange', function(){
                    $.fn.matchHeight._update();
                });
    
            }
            
            if( !isAdmin() ) {
                initialiseHeightMatch($block);
            }
        }

        // Initialize each block on page load (front end).
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.slider').each(function(){
                initialiseSliderImageBlock( $(this) );
            });
        });

        // Initialize dynamic block preview (editor).
        if( window.acf ) {
            window.acf.addAction( 'render_block_preview/type=image-slider', initialiseSliderImageBlock );
        }
```

### slider css

```
.slider { 
    position: relative; 
    z-index:1; 
    outline: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    .slide  { 
        height: 100%; 
        float: left !important; 
    }
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(n+2)   { display: none; }
.slider .slide.show-slide       { display: block; }

.slick-list,
.slick-track                    { height: 100%; }

.slick-slider .slick-slide      { float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; outline: none; }

.slick-list                     { overflow: hidden; outline: none !important; position: relative; }
.slick-track                    { margin: 0 auto; outline: none; }

.slick-next,
.slick-prev { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 84px;
    transition: 0.3s all ease;
    z-index: 10;
    
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    //background-image: url(../images-dist/icon-white-arrow-left.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}

.slick-next:hover,
.slick-prev:hover                       { width: 95px; }

.slick-next { 
    right: 0; 
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH"; 
}
.slick-prev                             { left: 0; }



ul.slick-dots {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        
        button {
            border: none;
            background-color: grey;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0 5px;
            font-size: 0;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        &.slick-active button {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    }
}
.image-slider-block {
&.is-cropped {
    .slick-track {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: stretch;
        .slick-slide > div {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
    img {
        height: 100%;
        flex: 1;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%; 
    } 
}
&.is-lightbox {
    a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue

Add this line to gutenberg editor css

```
.interface-interface-skeleton__editor {
  overflow: auto;
}
```